# gVim and Error Creating Window Handle

Tags: windows, vim

I use gVim on a day-to-day basis for editing files. I've noticed that, reliably, I can open a file at a UNC path, and when I do, a few things will happen: None of the menus in ANY app will open reliably, and there will be other strange effects, like Office not showing its toolbars, or Visual Studio throwing, "Error creating window handle" errors whenever I try to execute a statement. Does anyone have an idea what's going on, and how I can fix this apart from not using gVim to open files at UNC paths?